# How to test payable function with sending ethers to it?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, testing

How to test payable function with sending ethers to it? I mean how to write it?

```
await contact.payablefunction()   ###what should I write?
```

Comment: are u using etherjs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yuo are using etherjs then yuo need to add the amount of ether to send in the value. Example sending 0.01 ether:

```
const options = {value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.01")}
await contract.functioname( <args if it take arguments> , options)
```